# Multiple cell Search term and multiple cell Replace term using Regex in Excel

Tags: regex, excel

I have a fairly simple, but huge, Excel file with all my banking activity for an entire year in it.

I wish to tidy up a few formatting issues - balance amounts in the wrong column, and stuff like that.

I would like to search for places where formatting issues are present by using a regex search term that spans over multiple cells, and replace that search term with a term that would again span over multiple cells.

I have included an example below. 
I can not seem to get my regex search term to understand that I am searching using a multiple cell search term.

I have searched the forum here (and elsewhere via Google) but cannot seem to turn up anything like what i am trying to do.

I am new to this forum, and fairly new to regex, so I apologize if I am asking a basic or stupid question.

Here is a screen shot that I have scribbled on to try to explain my question ...

Search term regex would be something like - `(Opening Balance),(.*),(-*$\d*\s*\d*\D\d\d)` 
And Replace term might be something like - `\1,\2,\2,\2,\3`

Obviously, those expressions don't work like I want them to. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPFZq.png]
(Multiple cell Regex search/replace terms in Excel)

Comment: This looks like you want to move around data, in addition to manipulating it.  You should look into using VBA or possibly writing a macro for that.

Comment: Why can't you do this using a simple filter? You use a text filter, like "Contains Balance", you move the filtered values.

Comment: @Dominique - there are too many occurrences of this type of formatting task in my huge file to attempt replacements manually.

Comment: @Tim B - thanks for your reply. I would not know where to start with VBA or a macro. I was hoping there was a simple Regex solution, of which I was unaware, to pass the 'new cell' character(s). So are you saying this cannot be done with Regex ???

Comment: This question has not been answered for me.

Comment: This question has not been answered for me. Can anyone shed further light on this? Is it possible to create/insert a new extra cell by entering a new cell character in an existing cell? Is it possible or not?